# How do I split my code into functions for better readability?

Tags: c, function, morse-code

I have written a code which translates morse to text and vice versa. However, I am having a hard time to make them into simpler functions. I will have to submit the code into a makefile for which I need to split my code into two source code files- morse.c and main.c- and one header file morse.h. There is no problem regarding the makefile but only that I need to split m code into functions and not use any global variables for better clarity.

Code: https://onlinegdb.com/BJiDmG2A-

Any advice or direction would be really appreciated.

Just now I tried make a small part into a function but it does not work

```
  if (input[0] == '.' || input[0] == '-')
  { void MorseToText (input);
      printf("%s", result);
  } //go for morse to text conversion

   void MorseToText (char input,char result)
{               
    // Morse to Text translation part
     const char s[MATCH] = " ";
     char *section;
     int l;
     int check = 0;

    section = strtok (input, s);

    do
    {
        for (l = 0; l < DATA; l++)
        {

            if (!strcmp (section, table[l].morse))
            {
                check = check + 1;
                result = result + table[l].ascii; //printf ("%s", table[l].ascii);
            }
        }

        if (check == 0)
        {
            printf ("Invalid Morse code!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        section = strtok (NULL, s);
    }while (section != NULL);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please copy the code and paste here. Posting code on external link is not allowed as it'll become invalid if the link rots

Comment: the parameter "input" is  a string  it is should be cast as "char *". Why returning 0 from a void function this should generate warning from compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is better to start off writing the functions than to implement the functions after you have the code “done”.

I would look for code that completes a single task over and over again (for example, having functions that do the conversion, then havinga function that displays the output.)

You might be interested in return values. This lets your function interact with other functions, without using global variables.

Comment: Please have a look, sir, what's wrong with this function?

Comment: It seems you have a result, but you are not returning it. You would want to set “result” to  0 at the beginning of the function, and change it to whatever you want to return at the end of the function’s execution after your checks. Then, return the result value.  (If it is zero, then there was an error, otherwise, it will hold your value)